# How to fetch data form a retaliton?

Tags: node.js, swagger, postman, endpoint, strapi

I have created two **content type** with the builder, which are **categoria** and **restaurants** I need to fetch those data from it **relations** for example, all detail of **restaurant** if **categoria** name is tacos.

I need my API to work with the **postman**.

Comment: Do you need REST API ?

Answer (score 0):

If you will use GraphQL it is very easy.

Postman has GraphQL support. [Check its  docs.](https://www.postman.com/graphql/)

```
query restaurants {
  restaurants {
    id
    name
    categoria {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

---

You can use complex queries with REST API too.

https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/content-api/parameters.html#deep-filtering

For example:

```
/restaurants?_where[0][stars]=1&_where[1][pricing_lte]=20
```